# Limitation for update column in sql

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have a scenario to update the Employee details in Employee table.

**Employee**

```
EmpId  EmpName
---------------    
  1    james
  2    Anil
  3    Nandy
```

Multiple user will update the `EmpName` using `EmpId`

If one user updates the `Empname` from `Nandy` to `Peter`

**Employee**

```
EmpId  EmpName
----------------    
  1    james
  2    Anil
  3    Peter
```

In this situation I have to restrict the another user to update the same `EmpName` for 60 seconds.

If any user updates the `EmpName` `Peter` to `John` then I have to show alert message as *Please Update 60 seconds later*. I don't know how to achieve this in my application.

**Updated**

```
Private Function Getrecentaccountdatevalues() As DataTable
            Dim dsMaxdates As New DataSet
            Dim dtMaxdates As New DataTable
            Dim daMaxdates As SqlDataAdapter
            Try
                Dim strConnection As SqlClient.SqlConnection = New SqlClient.SqlConnection(strConnect(Me))
                Dim ocmdAofA As SqlClient.SqlCommand = New SqlClient.SqlCommand
                ocmdAofA.Connection = strConnection
                ocmdAofA.CommandText = "usp_getMaxdatesAofA"
                ocmdAofA.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                ocmdAofA.Parameters.Clear()
                ocmdAofA.Parameters.Add("@acc_AccountId", SqlDbType.Int, 15).Value = Request.QueryString("acct_AccountID")
                ocmdAofA.Parameters.Add("@client_ClientId", SqlDbType.Int, 15).Value = Request.QueryString("acct_ClientID")
                strConnection.Open()
                daMaxdates = New SqlDataAdapter(ocmdAofA)
                daMaxdates.Fill(dtMaxdates)
                strConnection.Close()
                strConnection.Dispose()
                ocmdAofA.Dispose()
            Catch ex As Exception
                Throw ex
            End Try
            Return dtMaxdates
        End Function
```

Comparing time while update the result.

```
Private Sub AofA_Update_Insert()
                Try

                    Dim accountNumber As String = Request.QueryString("acct_AccountID")
                    datatablerecentaccountvalues = Getrecentaccountdatevalues()
                    Dim dr As DataRow = datatablerecentaccountvalues.Rows(0)
                    Dim MaxUpdatedPrepped As DateTime = dr.Item("MaxUpdatedPrepped").ToString()
                    Dim Universaldatetime As DateTime = Now.ToUniversalTime()
                    Dim result As Integer = DateDiff(DateInterval.Second, MaxUpdatedPrepped, Universaldatetime)
                    If (result < 5 And accountNumber = GetrecentAccountID()) Then
                        ASPNET_MsgBox("Due to handling multiple user updates on same account at same time.Please Reset the page.")
                        Exit Sub
                    End If
End Try
```

Comment: Add a column, `LastUpdate` as a `DateTime` then compare the update with `Now()`, if it's greater the 60 seconds perform the update, otherwise throw and error?

Comment: Okay @RemarkLima but is there any option to restrict the update operation without adding any columns

Comment: Not really, how else will you know when it was last updated!? You could do it with a new table? Or do it via the `application` object?

Comment: @RemarkLima I added one TimeStamp Column and maintain the date time of updated datas.. I have another problem.. If the same time two users update the Empname i have to restrict the second user and alert like "Another User also update the same EmpId wait untill complete"...

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you add a TimeStamp Column, something like LastUpdate, and in your update query check if the new update is within the range or not?

**[Updated]**

```
IF (SELECT DATEDIFF(SECOND,LastUpdate,GETDATE())
FROM Table WHERE ID = @Id ) >= 60
BEGIN
    UPDATE Table ...
END
```

Comment: I added one TimeStamp Column and maintain the date time of updated datas.. I have another problem.. If the same time two users update the Empname i have to restrict the second user and alert like "Another User also update the same EmpId wait untill complete"...

Comment: Show us the code you're using so that we can give you the best advice.

Comment: That idea was not working for my scenario because if the two users try to update the EmpName then it will not work... because that situation trigger only after update the first user datas.. do you have any other idea to recover this scenario

Comment: If you mean, that when the user has the data on the screen and is about to change it, somehow you tell him/her that someone is editing it as well. My only idea is to add a flag in the database (i.e. UserEditing (bit)). Activate that flag when the first user retrieves the info, so that when the second user reads it you can display a message. But that can be problematic if the first user's App never resets the flag (due i.e. to an error). Or the flag could be a timestamp and you could add a restriction so if 1st user doesn't edit in a maximum time, 2nd user can edit...

Answer (score 0):

From your comment "but is there any option to restrict the update operation without adding any columns" I can only assume you're not allowed to touch the database? You could add a whole new table `tbl_LastUpdate`, with columns `ID`, `EmpId` and `LastUpdate` and use that as a link table to check?

However, if you can't change the database, depending on application load you could use a `dictionary` object stored in the `application` object:

```
Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)    
        Application("lastUpdate") = new Dictionary(of int, DateTime)
End Sub
```

(Forgive my VB, it's a little rusty! You may need to check)

Then when doing an update:

```
Sub updateEmpName(EmpId as Integer, EmpName as String)
     ' Get the Dictionary object
     Dim d as Dictionary
     d = Application("lastUpdate")

     if d.containsKey(EmpId) Then
         ' Check if the last update is greater than 60 seconds
         Dim dt as DateTime = d.Item(EmpId)
         if dt.AddSeconds(60) > DateTime.Now Then
            ' Do the update as greater then 60 seconds
            d.Item(EmpId) = DateTime.Now ' Set the datetime to now for this update
         else
            ' No update allowed
         End If
     else
        ' Update allowed as no key present
        d.Add(EmpId, DateTime.Now) ' Add the current ID and Timestamp to check
     End If

     ' Now loop through and clean up all old items in the dictionary to stop it getting to big
     For Each pair in d
         if pair.Value.AddSeconds(60) > DateTime.Now Then
              d.Remove(pair.key)
         End if
     Next        


     Application("lastUpdate") = d
End Sub
```

There's a good reference to the dictionary object here: http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary-vbnet

As said, my VB is really rusty so the code will need to be triple checked but hopefully it's enough to get you started!

Comment: That idea was not working for my scenario because if the two users try to update the EmpName then it will not work... because that situation trigger only after update the first user datas.. do you have any other idea to recover this scenario

Comment: But you can only check on update surely? Say the first user cancels the update? How does your interface work? Is there an edit screen? Then you'll have to look at locking the record if that's the case